# Why MSVC generates warning C4127 when constant is used in "while" - C

Tags: c, visual-c++, compiler-warnings, c4127

For code,

```
while(1)
{
   /* ..... */
}
```

MSVC generates the following warning.

```
warning C4127: conditional expression is constant
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h%28VS.80%29.aspx) page for the warning suggests to use `for(;;)` instead of `while(1)`. I am wondering what advantage `for(;;)` is giving and why it warns for the constant usage in `while`?

What flag should I use on GCC to get the same warning?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Constant conditionals are often enough simply bugs. Consider this:

```
unsigned k; 
...
while (k>=0) 
{
 ...
}
```

The condition `k>=0` would make sense if k was a signed int, but not for unsigned. A careless developer forgets that k was declared unsigned and he/she would use it as if it was usable as a negative number. The compiler tries to be helpful and warn you about this and  `while(1)` falls for the compiler into the same problem class. `for(;;)` is preferable because it unambiguously means `loop forever

Comment: The compiler is pretty smart; smart enough to do all kinds of magic, but not smart enough to understand that "while (true)" is not subject to those problems?

Answer (score 9):

`for(;;)` and `while (true)` are different in that the former is a special case *defined* to be an infinite loop, while the latter is sort of an abuse saying "true, always."

The warning comes up because infinite loops when [you don't want them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490823/why-msvc-generates-warning-c4127-whan-constant-is-used-in-while-c/3490834#3490834) are pretty bad, so it's warning you that you might have one at the first sign. But by using `for(;;)`, you've pretty much explicitly said "loop this forever", and there's nothing to warn about.

I don't think GCC has an equivalent warning.