# Is there a gcc warning for "conditional expression is constant"?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, android-ndk

I've inherited a sizeable codebase where someone, somehow, has written several conditionals like so:

```
enum
{
    FOO_TYPE_A,
    FOO_TYPE_B,
    FOO_TYPE_C,
    FOO_TYPE_D
};

void bar(int fooType)
{
    if (fooType == FOO_TYPE_A || FOO_TYPE_B) // <-- This will always be true, since FOO_TYPE_B is nonzero!
    {
        // Do something intended for only type A or B
    }

    // Do things general to A,B,C,D
}
```

where the condition check should clearly be:

```
    if (fooType == FOO_TYPE_A || fooType  == FOO_TYPE_B)
```

Is there a warning in gcc I can turn on to find them all, similar to MSDN's [C4127](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)?

Specifically, I'm using the Android NDK r9d.

If not, why not? It seems like a useful catch-all for unintentional assignment, unsigned > 0 as well as the above foolishness.

**EDIT:** Made the code more verbose to illustrate the problem.

Comment: I don't see any assignment in the condition.

Comment: Also, you can always try `g++ -Wpedantic -Wextra` and see what the gcc can possibly complain about.

Comment: The C4127 warning is more for something like `if (CONSTANT_1 == CONSTANT_2)` isn't it?

Comment: I think he mean if(var == 1 || 2)

Comment: Possible duplicate [Why MSVC generates warning C4127 whan constant is used in "while" - C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3490823)

Comment: You could `grep` for `||` amongst all the C files

Comment: I've updated my example to contrast what's there with what should be there.

Comment: @Edward C4127 will fire on `if(1)`, which is what this simplifies to.

Comment: @etheranger ah, now I see.  It wasn't clear at first that `CONSTANT_2` couldn't be zero.

Comment: Does C4127 kick in for `do { ... } while (0)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see a warning that corresponds to MSDN C4127. GCC does have a warning that is somewhat similar in intent, but not to address your problem: [`-Wtype-limits`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wtype-limits-436)

> Warn if a comparison is always true or always false due to the
>   limited range of the data type, but do not warn for constant
>   expressions.  For example, warn if an `unsigned` variable is compared
>   against zero with `<` or `>=`.  This warning is also enabled by
>   `-Wextra`.

As you can see, GCC explicitly states it does not warn about constant expressions. The motivation for this may be due to the common use of constant expressions to leverage the compiler's dead code elimination so that macros (or portions of it) can be optimized away by using a compile time constant. It would be used as an alternative to conditional compilation (`#if defined()` and `#if X == Y`), as the macro reads more naturally like a regular function. As a hypothetical example:

```
#define VERIFY(E) \
do { \
    if (NO_VERIFY) break; \
    if (!(E) && (VERIFY_LOG_LEVEL >= log_level() || VERIFY_LOG_ALWAYS)) { \
        log("validation error for: " #E); \
    } \
} while (0)
```

Comment: I agree that such a hypothetical warning shouldn't be on by default, but there are always situations when some warnings will fire spuriously (parameters unused in debug builds, anyone?). That doesn't mean it wouldn't be helpful to have the option.  In any case, this is as good an answer as possible, so I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that variable is a define or a const. CONSTANT_2 is a non-zero constant also make this problem.

Comment: I think he speaking about `|| CONSTANT_2` it should turn into `if(.. || 2)` in this case a warning could be useful

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, and didn't read the question serious. I think the problem is that variable is a define or a const. CONSTANT_2 is a non-zero constant also make this problem.