# Warning if you accidentially compare constants using boolean operators (||, &&)

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Is there a way to make clang (or gcc) warn you if you use integer constants with boolean operators? Specifically (but not only) in an `if` context?

What I mean is, I wrote:

```
enum MatchType {MATCHED, FAKE, DUMMY};

if (matchType == MatchType::FAKE || MatchType::DUMMY) {
    // ...
}
```

where it should have been

```
if (matchType == MatchType::FAKE || matchType == MatchType::DUMMY) {
```

The OR operation with a constant clearly doesn't make sense (especially when it is not a literal 0 or 1). Any idea how to prevent this? (I know using `switch` would be the right thing to do in this specific case, and would prevent this kind of mistake, but I'm still interested in an answer.)

The similar question ["is there a gcc warning for conditional expression is constant"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22852364/146325) is focused on the case where you have an expression in an `if` that - after simplification - is constant. I'm asking about the case where you use boolean operators on non-bool constants, for example:

```
bool result = flags && 42;  // you might have meant `&`
```

Also, in this case the conditional expression is *not* constant (depends on `a`), but it is probably still a mistake:

```
if (a == 5 && 6) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852364/is-there-a-gcc-warning-for-conditional-expression-is-constant

Comment: The other question overlaps my question, and actually addresses my *concrete* problem. But the question *as asked* is different... I'm asking about using `||` and `&&` on non-bools. You can have cases where "the conditional expression is *not* constant", or you are not using `if` at all, and I'd still like a warning.

Comment: By "constants", you mean `constexpr` (compile-time constant), not `const` (dynamic initialization but immutable thereafter), correct?

Comment: @BenVoigt Neither specifically. I mean mostly literals, but also enum values, yes also `constexpr`, and whatever the compiler happens to deduce at compile time.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't help you, you have to do the check yourself at compile time. In case of enums, a wrapper class can do the trick, something like this: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Safe_Enum

Comment: For the record, both GCC 10 and Clang 10 warn about this with `-Wall`.

Answer (score 0):

Recent version of gcc and clang provides `Wint-in-bool-context` warning which checks exactly this.

Alternatively, if you're using C+11, you can use `enum class`

```
enum class MatchType {MATCHED, FAKE, DUMMY};
```

(I'm assuming your compiler supports C++11, since you're using `MatchType::FAKE` to reference the enum instead of `FAKE`)

`enum class` provides better type safety than plain `enum`. See [Why is enum class preferred over plain enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335861/why-is-enum-class-preferred-over-plain-enum)