# Why do I see people use for(;;) more than while(1) for infinite loops?

Tags: c, gcc, visual-c++, g++, conventions

I see `for(;;)` used much more frequently than `while(1)` in the wild, and I am curious if there is any meaningful reason for this. Compiling using GCC with -O0 optimization, both statements yield a single jump instruction. Is it more than just a coding style? Are there any coding standards that state that `for(;;)` is preferred over `while(1)`? Is there some efficiency reason that I'm missing? I realize that the goal is usually to make code the most readable that it can be, but I don't see much of a difference between the two styles as far as readability to warrant such a stark difference in usage.

Comment: maybe because while(1) involve a value (costant 1) whereas for(;;) Is pure statement

Comment: Seems like some compilers generate different code https://godbolt.org/z/9Kqqex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while(1)` involves a constant which might result in an overhead when compiling without optimization such as pushing 1 and checking if the expression is z,n or positive.

MSVC demo with `while(1)`
https://godbolt.org/z/MMMT9n

```
$LN2@main:
    mov eax, 1
    test eax, eax
    je SHORT $LN1@main
    jmp SHORT $LN2@main
$LN1@main:
```

With `for(;;)`

```
$LN4@main:
    jmp SHORT $LN4@main
```

Comment: Very neat website. It seems that the switch from GCC to MSVC causes that extra inefficiency to show.

Comment: @KevinMontambault - is there any reason to talk about efficiency of not optimized code? With even default optimization, there will only be one `jmp`...

Comment: Who does actually care about the efficiency of the -O0 generated code?

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland no one should. But OP asked if there's any difference between them and I showed an example in which the generated code differs for `-O0`

Answer (score 2):

With some older compilers, for example, Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 before update 3, the `while(1)` construct will trigger a warning about conditional expression being constant, see [Remarks section for warning C4127](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4127).

A related question was asked on Stack Overflow over ten years ago about this, see [Why MSVC generates warning C4127 when constant is used in “while”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3490823/1458097).

I remember stumbling upon this, back in the days when we were using Visual Studio 2012. Nowadays, this seems to be sorted out, but still, the `for(;;)` form seems more idiomatic to me.